# Problem deploying K8s with gitlab runner get an error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I changed something and deployed on a new cluster then I got this error even though I didn't change anything in the code. Has anybody seen it before?

from server for:

```
"/builds/dropcunt/nettmoster.com/deployment/webapp.yml": ingresses.extensions "nettmoster.comn-273414" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default" cannot get resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "nettmoster-com-9777808"
59 Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
```

As suggested I run`kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default`

It returns: 
[image]

Comment: Hello, did the solution provided bellow solved your issue? Would you like to learn more about kubernetes authentication RBAC as a whole?

Comment: Hello Willrof. Thanks for asking. I got rid off this error in the pipeline. I'm have an SSH problem now i'm not sure if it could be related to this.

Comment: That's great! But I'd advice you to post your SSH issue as a new question, since it's not related to the original question. Good luck!

Comment: thanks so much! Hava a good day and stay healthy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a RBAC problem. The service account `system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default` does not have permission to get `ingress` resource in the new cluster.

You can compare what permission a service account have by running below command in both the cluster

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default
```

Run below commands to get permission via RBAC

```
kubectl create role ingress-reader --verb=get,list,watch,update --resource=ingress    
kubectl create rolebinding ingress-reader-role --role=ingress-reader --serviceaccount=gitlab-managed-apps:default
```

Comment: how do I fix this i'm new with RBAC

Comment: as I said you need run the command in both the cluster and provide the output...do you have admin access to the cluster?

Comment: I only have one cluster running if this was not clear

Comment: thanks so much I got rid of the error! Now i have an SSH unfortunetally that was not there before. Do you think that could be connected to the fact that RCAB has to be enabled now? How can I check if certmanager in the gitlab-managed-apps has enough rights to make the cainjection?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with details